# Unable to set value to the object in aura component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, salesforce1-app

I am trying to populate the custom component with the record. 
and here is the component.

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global" 
                controller="EngagementController" >
   <aura:attribute name="Engagements" type="String[]" />  
   <aura:attribute name="recordId" type="String" />

   <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}" />

   <force:recordData aura:id="recordLoader" 
                      recordId="{!v.recordId}"
                      fields="Id, ONPATTRO_Indication_MVN__c,
                              ONPATTRO_Indication_Notes__c,
                              ONPATTRO_Efficacy_Safety_MVN__c,
                              ONPATTRO_Efficacy_Safety_Notes__c,
                              ONPATTRO_Mechanism_Action_MVN__c,
                              ONPATTRO_Mechanism_Action_Notes__c,
                              ONPATTRO_Dosing_Administration_MVN__c,
                              ONPATTRO_Dosing_Administration_Notes__c,
                              ONPATTRO_Infusion_MVN__c,
                              ONPATTRO_Infusion_Notes__c,
                              Alnylam_Assist_Review_MVN__c,
                              Alnylam_Assist_Review_Notes__c,
                              hATTR_Review_MVN__c,
                              hATTR_Review_Notes__c,
                              hATTR_Hereditary_Nature_MVN__c,
                              hATTR_Hereditary_Nature_Notes__c,
                              hATTR_Symptoms_MVN__c,
                              hATTR_Symptoms_Notes__c,
                              hATTR_Amyloidosis__c,
                              hATTR_Amyloidosis_Notes__c,
                              hATTR_Amyloidosis_risk__c,
                              hATTR_Amyloidosis_risk_Notes__c,
                              hATTR_Resources_MVN__c,
                              hATTR_Resources_Notes__c,
                              Alnylam_Act_Review_MVN__c,
                              Alnylam_Act_Review_Notes__c"
                      targetFields="{!v.Engagements}"/>

    <div class="slds-tile__detail  slds-scrollable--y"   >
        <dl class="slds-list_horizontal slds-wrap">
            <dt class="slds-item_label slds-text-color_weak" Style="text-align:center; margin: 2px 2px; width:50%;" >
                <input type="checkbox" name="default" /> 
                Indication of ONPATTRO {!v.Engagements.Id}

            </dt>

        </dl>
    </div>
</aura:component>
```

where

```
 <aura:attribute name="recordId" type="String" />
```

is populated form another component.

`<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}" />` function is running fine but when it comes to setting up values to Engagements 
 `component.set("v.Engagements", result);` function is not working in following controller.

```
({
    doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
        var action = component.get("c.getDiscussion");
        var recordId = component.get("v.recordId");
        alert(recordId);
      action.setParams({ "recordId":recordId });
        console.log(component.get("v.recordId"));
        action.setCallback(this, function(e) {
           if(e.getState()=='SUCCESS'){
                var result=e.getReturnValue(); 
               console.log(result);
                component.set("v.Engagements", result);
            }
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    },

})
```

the Apex controller is given here.

```
@AuraEnabled
    public static PEL_Engagement_MVN__c getDiscussion(String recordId) {
        system.debug('****'+recordId);
        PEL_Engagement_MVN__c Engagement = [Select  Id,ONPATTRO_Indication_MVN__c,
                                                    ONPATTRO_Indication_Notes__c,
                                                    ONPATTRO_Efficacy_Safety_MVN__c,
                                                    ONPATTRO_Efficacy_Safety_Notes__c,
                                                    ONPATTRO_Mechanism_Action_MVN__c,
                                                    ONPATTRO_Mechanism_Action_Notes__c,
                                                    ONPATTRO_Dosing_Administration_MVN__c,
                                                    ONPATTRO_Dosing_Administration_Notes__c,
                                                    ONPATTRO_Infusion_MVN__c,
                                                    ONPATTRO_Infusion_Notes__c,
                                                    Alnylam_Assist_Review_MVN__c,
                                                    Alnylam_Assist_Review_Notes__c,
                                                    hATTR_Review_MVN__c,
                                                    hATTR_Review_Notes__c,
                                                    hATTR_Hereditary_Nature_MVN__c,
                                                    hATTR_Hereditary_Nature_Notes__c,
                                                    hATTR_Symptoms_MVN__c,
                                                    hATTR_Symptoms_Notes__c,
                                                    hATTR_Amyloidosis__c,
                                                    hATTR_Amyloidosis_Notes__c,
                                                    hATTR_Amyloidosis_risk__c,
                                                    hATTR_Amyloidosis_risk_Notes__c,
                                                    hATTR_Resources_MVN__c,
                                                    hATTR_Resources_Notes__c,
                                                    Alnylam_Act_Review_MVN__c,
                                                    Alnylam_Act_Review_Notes__c
                                                    from    PEL_Engagement_MVN__c 
                                                    where Id =: recordId];
    System.debug('Hi ::::' +Engagement);
        return Engagement;
    }
```

Thanks Advance.

Comment: can you show `getDiscussion` apex method and also what you are getting in log

Comment: okay let me edit my my question you will see it

Answer (score 1):

`Engagements` will be automatically be populated with values for mentioned fields for the record as its using lightning data service [force:recordData](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/force:recordData/documentation). Also it should be of type `Object` instead of `String[]` - else it will not load.

You dont need `doInit` method and apex method as you are just fetching same record.

Use `aura:if` since you are passing it from another component. When does `recordId` gets passed to this component depends on how the parent component is processing it.

```
<aura:attribute name="Engagements" type="Object" />  
<aura:attribute name="recordId" type="String" />

<aura:if isTrue="{!not(empty(v.recordId))}">
    <force:recordData aura:id="recordLoader" 
                      recordId="{!v.recordId}"
                      fields="Id, ONPATTRO_Indication_MVN__c,
                              ONPATTRO_Indication_Notes__c,
                              ONPATTRO_Efficacy_Safety_MVN__c,
                              ONPATTRO_Efficacy_Safety_Notes__c,
                              ONPATTRO_Mechanism_Action_MVN__c,
                              ONPATTRO_Mechanism_Action_Notes__c,
                              ONPATTRO_Dosing_Administration_MVN__c,
                              ONPATTRO_Dosing_Administration_Notes__c,
                              ONPATTRO_Infusion_MVN__c,
                              ONPATTRO_Infusion_Notes__c,
                              Alnylam_Assist_Review_MVN__c,
                              Alnylam_Assist_Review_Notes__c,
                              hATTR_Review_MVN__c,
                              hATTR_Review_Notes__c,
                              hATTR_Hereditary_Nature_MVN__c,
                              hATTR_Hereditary_Nature_Notes__c,
                              hATTR_Symptoms_MVN__c,
                              hATTR_Symptoms_Notes__c,
                              hATTR_Amyloidosis__c,
                              hATTR_Amyloidosis_Notes__c,
                              hATTR_Amyloidosis_risk__c,
                              hATTR_Amyloidosis_risk_Notes__c,
                              hATTR_Resources_MVN__c,
                              hATTR_Resources_Notes__c,
                              Alnylam_Act_Review_MVN__c,
                              Alnylam_Act_Review_Notes__c"
                      targetFields="{!v.Engagements}"/>

    <div class="slds-tile__detail  slds-scrollable--y"   >
        <dl class="slds-list_horizontal slds-wrap">
            <dt class="slds-item_label slds-text-color_weak" Style="text-align:center; margin: 2px 2px; width:50%;" >
                <input type="checkbox" name="default" /> 
                Indication of ONPATTRO {!v.Engagements.Id}
            </dt>

        </dl>
    </div>
</aura:if>
```

Comment: by setting the String[] to Object type I am still getting the results

Comment: I have edit my question and share the Apex class.

Comment: It should be only Object type. Check the answer